# Get JS script in JSON notation and parse without assigning variable to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JS file that has the following "JSON-like" object and would like to consume it via $.getScript method or other and then parse it:

```
{
  name : "My Test",
  paramOne : "value",
  paramTwo : [
    {
      desc : "Click button to change text of container",
      trigger : function(){ doSomething(); },
      paramThree : [
        {
          desc : "Description here",
          action : function(){ return true; }
        },
        {
          desc : "Description here 2",
          action : function(){ return 0; }
        }
      ]
    }
};
```

I've tried jQuery methods `$.getScript` and `$.getJSON` and can't seem to parse it without assigning a variable to this object. I don't want to assign it a variable name. I was hoping to do something like this:

```
$.getScript('example.js', function(data, status, xhr){
    myMethod.parseObject(data);
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: JSON objects can't contain functions, only data.

Comment: That's really not "JSON-like" at all. And as a script, it's not a valid program.

Comment: If you just add something like `var foo =` to the start of it, then it will be able to be parsed and run as valid JS code.

Comment: That is why I said it is "JSON-like." It has methods in it on purpose. If I assign this object with a variable name like var obj = {}; then I can reference it as obj.paramOne etc. I just want to know if I can get away with it without assigning a variable name to the object. For example, read the object, send it to a method to parse it and perform X actions.

Comment: @Freddie: I would suggest adding `var obj =` (like you say works) to this file and load it that way.  If you wanted to save this data as *JSON* and load it in that way, then you would need a way to serialize/unserialize the functions - which is too much work for no reason.  *Why* do you not want to assign a variable name?

Comment: If you have to do it like that way put these functions as  string then while parsing use eval () function to evaluate it . (use of eval() is not recommended otherwise)

Comment: And I said it's not  "JSON-like" because it's really very little like JSON data. You can't have the JS engine parse and execute it in its current form. You need some kind of modification. If you just don't want to change the file but don't mind doing it on the client, then you could fetch it as plain text, and do `var obj = new Function("return " + textData.trim())()`, which creates a new function which has a single `return` statement that returns the value of the text data.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - There will be potentially hundreds of these kinds of objects / files and I want the user of the system to not have to provide unique variable names and keep track of them. I want my system to not require unique variable names so that these types of objects could be autogenerated and fed into my system.

Comment: I think you are trying to create a DSL (Domain specific language) and attempting to shoehorn javascript in directly, but it wont be so straight forward. You will need to create a syntax which you can both generate and parse in order to achieve the desired results.

Comment: @Freddie: Then why not put them all into one object (like a namespace).  At the beginning of *each* file: `var myObj = myObj || {};`.  Then: `myObj['fileName'] = {};`.  That way *all* your objects will be contained inside one `myObj` object with keys set as you wish.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - ooh - I will try that and see if it can fit the model that I want. Back with some feedback. Thanks.